# unix date to millisecond is giving invalid date error

Tags: shell, date, unix

I have date format like "

date: invalid date `2015-08-19T14:36:08Z'

date: invalid date `2015-08-19T22:36:09Z'

date: invalid date `2015-08-19T00:00:00Z'
"

I tried:

```
somedate="2015-08-19T00:00:00Z"

date1=$(date -d "$somedate"+%s)

echo $date1
```

When I'm trying to convert into milliseconds, it gives me error:invalid date

Comment: I solved the issue by removing a "Z" character at the end using sed and it worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert the time to epoch seconds. Try like this

```
date1=$(date -d "$somedate" "+%s")
```

Mention the `%s` separately.